# Want to make Multiple line graphs using 2 different Worksheets with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I want to start out by saying this is my first attempt at using VBA to do something in Excel. I have created a large (400 rows by 30 columns give or take) data collection spreadsheet and want to generate line graphs for each row of data.

The data is segregated into different buckets depending on what it is relevant too and each bucket has its own worksheet. In the data generation sheet I have all my raw data, then on each separate worksheet there is target data for each line item related to that bucket.

Essentially this excel workbook has a page of historian generated operations data and I want to make visualizations for each using different worksheets. I have found many different threads on here but I am either incapable of understanding them well enough to put them to use or they are not doing what I need them too.

Ultimately I want to write a script that I can use 1 time per worksheet to generate graphs that will automatically update from that time on.

This is where I got from a coding standpoint and it WAS working sort of, but it would only generate target lines. which is half of what I need.

```
Sub New_Macro()
    Dim i As Long, ntop As Long, nleft As Long
    Dim strchrt As String
    
    i = 34: nleft = 20: ntop = 20
    
    a = 2
    
    For i = 34 To 53
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ("='Data Generation'!(i, 2)")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Data Generation'!$H$i:$AK$i")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(a, 25), Cells(a, 54))
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
        
        strchr = Trim(Replace(ActiveChart.Name, ActiveSheet.Name, ""))
        
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strchrt).Left = nleft
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(strchrt).Top = ntop
        
        ntop = ntop + ActiveSheet.Shapes(strchrt).Height = 20
        i = i + 1
        a = a + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and define `a` - `Dim a as Long`.

When using variables in a string, you can't wrap it in quotation marks. For example:

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Data Generation'!$H$i:$AK$i")`

should be:

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Data Generation'!$H$" & i & ":$AK$" & i)`

and

`ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ("='Data Generation'!(i, 2)")`

should be:

`ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ("='Data Generation'!(" & i & ", 2)")`

Comment: You should also fully qualify all your `Range`s and `Cells`.

Comment: That is helpful, I assumed the syntax would be the same as a normal cell reference.. I will plug this in tomorrow and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so I made those changes. VBA did not like having option explicit in there. It is still only generating 1 y-axis series (the one that is on the same work sheet). Am I doing something wrong with my referece? This is how it's now written "ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("='Data Generation'!$H$" & i & ":$AK$" & i)